# Git merge and pushing to the right branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have two branches. Branch A which is the team working branch and then branch B which is my own personal development branch. When I am trying to merge branch B to the branch A and I am currently in branch B do I need to add, commit and push changes to the origin A or origin B before I checkout to A and merge B to it?

Comment: In an ideal world, you shouldn't have everyone merging to the shared branch locally, this will lead to pain.  Consider using a PR-based workflow, or nominate a single gatekeeper of the shared branch.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to commit your changes to the B branch.

Assuming you are on your B branch:

```
# git add file1 file2 file3 ...
# git commit -m "you know improving everything cause i'm awesome"
# git checkout A
# git merge B
# echo "you MAY need to commit the merge, sometimes this is done automagically"
# echo "now if you want your changes to be pushed..."
# git push A
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you be able to tell my why the last push is to the branch B instead of A where I am currently then?